# Express.js subapps loading same module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple Express app that loads 2 subapps - login and posts. The subapps and the top level app each import some common code using distinct require statements, yet when the code runs it looks like they are sharing the same code.

File structure is:

```
├── app.js
├── lib
│   ├── Common.js
│   ├── login
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── posts
│       └── index.js
└── package.json
```

app.js:

```
var
  express  = require( 'express' ),
  Common   = require( './lib/Common' ),
  login    = require( './lib/login' ),
  posts    = require( './lib/posts' ),
  app      = express();

app.use( login );
app.use( posts );
Common.init( "top level" );
app.listen( 3000 );
```

lib/login/index.js: (lib/posts/index.js is similar)

```
var
  express = require( 'express' ),
  Common  = require( '../Common' ),
  app     = module.exports = express();

Common.init( "login subapp" );
```

lib/Common.js:

```
var stored_text = undefined;

init = function ( text ) {
  console.log( "text: " + text );
  console.log( "before: " + stored_text );
  stored_text = text;
  console.log( "after: " + stored_text );
}

module.exports = {
  init: init
}
```

When I run the app I get the following output:

```
node app.js 
text: login subapp
before: undefined
after: login subapp
text: posts subapp
before: login subapp
after: posts subapp
text: top level
before: posts subapp
after: top level
```

I was expecting each app to have its own copy of the code, so "before: undefined" would have been printed 3 times. Instead only the first app to load prints this line, the next to load have the stored_text variable set from the first app.

Is there a way to safely share code between apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior - the fact that `require` caches and reuses, is pretty well-documented and highly desirable as it allows one app to have multiple js files `require('x')` and all of them will be touching the same x, versus having to create some other method to share.

Generally speaking, if I understand your goals, the approach you will probably want to take for your solution is to rework `'Common.js` into more "class" like structures and have each app use a new instance. You already have chosen to capitalize Common for some reason (by a broadly-used convention, only 'constructor' functions have an initial capital), so it will look similar.

Something like:

For Common.js

```
// this is a constructor
var Common = function(initStr)
{
   this.storedText = initStr;
}

module.exports = Common;
```

In your index.js (and other files)

```
var Common = require('../Common');

var common = new Common ("instance string");

// code access 'common' from here.
```

If you did this in multiple files, each file would have its own `common` even though the all share a common `Common`, if you will.

You could enhance this further to allow some sort of keyed access so that if you needed file A and file B to share a single `common` instance, you could make it available, but I think the above should address your immediate inquiry.

Hope this helps. If you need some further clarification, please comment and I will keep an eye out.

**UPDATE**

As you requested in the comment, an approach you could take for the keyed sharing of instances would be something like this:

For Common.js

```
// this is a constructor
var Common = function(key, initStr)
{
   if(Common.instances[key])
       return Common.instances[key]

   this.storedText = initStr;
   Common.instances[key] = this;
}

Common.instances= {};

module.exports = Common;
```

Then you could just access the same instances of it from various files as:

```
specificButShareable = new Common('postsModule', 'instance data for posts');
```

Note that as implemented, if a second file is loaded with

```
specificButShareable = new Common('postsModule', 'some other instance data');
```

the returned common would still have 'instance data for posts' rather than 'some other instance data'. Obviously you could change that behavior if you wanted, but the above is sort of the bare bones version of the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, really helpful. I was able to get your suggested solution working. Could you outline the shared single instance enhancement you mentioned? That sounds like it could be a good way to share data between apps.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an update to the answer to elaborate.

Comment: Barry thanks this is really cool stuff, it hadn't occurred to me that you could add properties to functions, or that you could make the property a reference back to the instance(s). Still trying to get my head around some of the intricacies of javascript. Cheers.

Comment: If you are used to many other languages the idea of a funciton having properties is a little bizarre, but is the benefit (or feature at a minimum) of Javascript's functional nature. I recommend Douglas Crockford's lectures (can find on Youtube - [here's a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB) for his YUI Conf talks) or book _Javascript: The Good Parts_ as useful aids for a deeper understanding of Javascript.